# AWS Amplify can't connect with Elastic BeansTalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify, amazon-elb

I created an API using Spring Boot and deploy it using Elastic Beanstalk.
I use AWS Amplify to create a frontend that consumes the API.
Because AWS Amplify uses HTTPS and the Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer uses HTTP I get a Mixed Content error.
In order to solve this error, I created a self-signed certificate and followed this Tutorial to enable HTTPS in the load balancer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Now the problem is that  I get a NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID  error.

Currently, I don't know what else I can do to make my frontend talk with my API. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> self-signed certificate

It can't be self signed. You need **valid public SSL certificate** for your own domain that you control. AWS ACM can give you such a certificate which you can easily deploy later on your load balancer.

Thus, you need to get your **own domain** for which later you can register the SSL certificate.